# get video stream from browser to opencv?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, opencv

I am currently doing a project where I would like to take a video stream from browser and be able to process it in opencv while it is playing. so for now I am thinking of using selenium chrome driver as the browser, does anyone have an idea how I can get the video stream from selenium to opencv ?
P.S. I am thinking of getting a video stream from google meets or any video streaming platform

Comment: It would be helpful if u provide the link from where u r trying to extract the video stream.

Comment: I am thinking of getting a video steam google meets or zoom ,thanks for the heads-up, ill edit the questions!